# Why is a Ruby setter method returning a String rather than a Symbol as the last expression evaluated?

Tags: ruby, string, casting, symbols, setter

### Unexpected Return Value from Method: Expecting Symbol

I have the following Ticket class:

```
class Ticket
  VALID_STATES = %i[open closed invalid wontfix]
  attr_reader :status
  def status= new_state
    new_state = new_state.to_sym
    @status = new_state
  end
end
```

When passed a String rather than a Symbol, the setter method unexpectedly returns a String, even though the correct value is being returned by the getter method. For example:

```
t = Ticket.new
t.status = 'closed'
#=> "closed"

t.status
#=> :closed
```

It looks like the correct value is being *stored* as a Symbol, but I'm at a loss as to why the method is returning `"closed"` at the REPL when the last expression evaluated should return `:closed`. My expectation is that the expression in question ought to resolve as `@status = :closed`, and therefore should return a Symbol.

Can anyone explain why I'm getting a String rather than a Symbol as the return value from the setter method?

### Caveats and Bike-Shedding Prevention

1. I know this example could just use `@status = new_state.to_sym` rather than assigning back to *new_state*, but there's intermediate code that was removed to create this minimal example. I didn't want to change the code too much, as that defeats the point of showing what my real code is doing. It doesn't seem to make a difference for this specific problem anyway; I've tried it both ways.
2. I tried this with Ruby 2.3.1, 2.4.0-preview2, and JRuby 9.1.4.0, so it's not version-specific.
3. Various debugging attempts ran afoul of other issues specific to the REPL's toplevel in both Pry and IRB, which I will open as a separate question. The point here is that trying to debug with alternative abstractions like `def foo=(str); @foo = str.to_sym; end` leads further down the rabbit hole.
4. It's extremely possible that the problem exists between the keyboard and the chair, but the focus of the question is really about why the **return value** is not of the expected class.

Comment: I really like such well-prepared questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's expected. From the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Return+Values):

> Note that for assignment methods the return value will always be
>   ignored. Instead, the argument will be returned:
>
> ```
> def a=(value)
>   return 1 + value
> end
>
> p(a = 5) # prints 5
> ```

Ruby allows you to chain assignments:

```
foo = bar = 'closed'
```

The above assigns `"closed"` to both, `foo` and `bar`.

Returning the argument and ignoring the method's return value lets you replace `bar` with a method call:

```
foo = t.status = 'closed'
```

IMO it would be quite surprising if the above would assign `:closed` to `foo`.

If you really want the return value, use `send` or `public_send`:

```
def a=(value)
  return 1 + value
end

p(a = 5)        # prints 5
p(send(:a=, 5)) # prints 6
```

Comment: Thanks for the link to the docs. You're right that it appears to be a documented corner case that applies only to assignment methods (not assignment expressions), but it's still surprising to me because I would expect the same behavior as `foo = 'a'.to_sym #=> :a`. Clearly that's not the case, though. :/

Answer (score 1):

The answer is rather simple: in Ruby, assignments evaluate to the value being assigned. There's nothing special about method assignments.

Comment: I often agree with your answers, but can't in this case. Inside the method, the value being assigned is a Symbol. So while the documentation calls out method assignment for different behavior, "the value assigned" is a Symbol, not a String.

Comment: @CodeGnome that are two different assignments. You have `@status = new_state` inside your method, which evaluates to `new_state` (i.e. `:closed`). And you have `t.status = 'closed'` outside your method which evaluates to `"closed"`. The inner assignment doesn't affect the outer one in any way. The return value is always the value on the right-hand side.